# Traefik as reverse proxy with certbot / lego

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, certbot, traefik

When setting up a server I use a reverse proxy and acme tool for dns01 support (I use either nginx + certbot or nginx + lego). I want to start using traefik instead.

I don't understand how traefik interacts with certbot (or lego, etc.), and I can't find relevant examples. I found many examples for getting certs using traefik itself.

Is certbot/lego not needed at all in a traefik setup? Can it do everything certbot can do?

Comment: what do you want to archive. it's in the moment unclear.

Comment: so if your question is solved, please add an answer and after 24h please mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like traefik uses lego internally - so it can do whatever lego can do (I assume).

Therefore as far as I can tell, certbot/lego/etc. is not needed anymore.